# js discord bot,random message every time without restart

Tags: node.js, discord.js

```js
var messages = ["Message1", "Message2", "Message3"]

var randomMessage = messages[Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length)];

client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;

    const { commandName } = interaction;
    if (commandName === 'ping') {
        await interaction.reply('Pong!');
        await interaction.channel.send(randomMessage)
    }
});
```

I want this to send a random message every time the `ping` command is run. How can I get that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Before asking a question, please read the [How to ask Section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And try to explain your problem in a clear and easily understandable manner.

Comment: You're generating the random number in the file outside of a listener therefor the number will only be generated once on every run

Comment: thx! Elitezen! your comment are so good to me

Answer (score 2):

As of now, you are only picking a random message in the array once. As a result, the message will always be the same whenever you use it. In order to keep picking new random messages, place the `var randomMessage = messages[Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length)]` line inside the client.on function.

Comment: thx!!! i was work!! your are a genius